# Drawable size Depend on screen size

Tags: android

I'm trying to develop android app, and customize listview as below:

TextView [] CheckBox

and now I want to display Drawable inside text but I have problem of icon size

How I can set Drawable size depend on screen size?

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.country_info1, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.code = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.code);
        holder.name = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    //display icon of all apps.
    AppList country = appListSelected.get(position);
    try {
        Drawable icon = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(country.getCode());                  
        icon.setBounds(0, 0, 72, 72);
        holder.code.setCompoundDrawables(icon, null, null, null);
        holder.code.setText("");
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    }

    holder.name.setText(country.getName());
    holder.name.setChecked(country.isSelected());
    holder.name.setTag(country);

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Add your dimension in resource folder (in dimen.xml). And get it in code :
int size = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.icon_size). Then use this size in setCompoundDrawable

Comment: but setCompoundDrawable(Drawable, Drawable, Drawable, Drawable) So how to set size

Comment: sorry, not setCompoundDrawables, but setBounds